# ¿Cómo pasar un char [] desde el Modelo hasta la Vista (MVC) en JAVA?

Tags: java, array, mvc

Estamos realizando el juego "Ahorcado" y estamos atascados a la hora de pasar el ARRAY de char que hemos obtenido a través de la clase random para que se visualice en la ventana a través de

g.drawChars(...........);

Pongo los códigos correspondientes que tengo por el momento en las clases: PRINCIPAL, VISTA, MODELO Y CONTROLADOR.

A ver si entre todos conseguimos resolverlo. Gracias y un saludo.

```
**PRINCIPAL**

import javax.swing.*;

    public class Principal {
        public static void main(String[] args)  {
            Vista view = new Vista();
            view.setVisible(true);
            view.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            Controlador c = new Controlador();
        }
    }
```

VISTA

```
public class Vista extends JFrame{
Controlador controlador;


public Vista() {
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
    this.controlador = new Controlador();
    this.addKeyListener(controlador);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) { // g es un objeto gráfico y contiene los métodos de pintado
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500); // para crear un rectángulo
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    this.controlador.getModelo();
 }
}
```

**MODELO**

```
 import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public

class Modelo {

static Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

/*** DECLARACIÓN DE VARIABLES ***/

String[] listaDeportes = {"futbol, baloncesto, balonmano, tenis, ski, padel, ciclismo, natacion, petanca, hipica"};
int errores;
char[] estadoPalabra;
char[] letrasErroneas;
String palabraSecreta;
Random numAlea = new Random();
Vista view;

/*** CONSTRUCTOR ***/

public Modelo(int errores, String palabraSecreta, char[] estadoPalabra) {
    this.errores = errores;
    this.palabraSecreta = listaDeportes[(int) (numAlea.nextDouble() * 10)];
    for (int i = 0; i < palabraSecreta.length(); i++) {
        this.estadoPalabra[i] = '_';
    }
    view = new Vista();
}

public char[] getEstadoPalabra() {
    return estadoPalabra;
}

public void verificar(char letra) {

    for (int i = 0; i < palabraSecreta.length(); i++) {
        if (palabraSecreta.toCharArray()[i]==(letra)) {
            estadoPalabra[i] = letra;
        }
        else
            errores++;
    }
}
```

**CONTROLADOR**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Controlador implements KeyListener {

private Vista view;
private Modelo modelo;
String palabraSecreta;
char[] estadoPalabra;
int errores;


public Modelo getModelo(){
    return modelo;
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    char letra = e.getKeyChar();
    System.out.println(letra);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}
}
```

Comment: Hola bienvenido. Tienes un error de concepto sobre MVC. Deben ser paquetes y no clases. Cada paquete contiene clases que ejercen funciones según el paquete. Aqui algo de info http://codejavu.blogspot.mx/2013/06/ejemplo-modelo-vista-controlador.html.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo de paquetes, la verdad. Nosotros aún no estamos en ese nivel, "creo". Yo simplemente quería pasar el array de char a la vista para que lo pinte

Comment: ok. Cual es la palabra que quieres pasar? Es `String palabraSectreta`?

Answer (score 0):

Aqui te va un ejemplo de tu código modificado. Estudialo e implementa lo que te sirva.

**PRINCIPAL**

```
    public class Principal {
        public static void main(String[] args)  {
            Vista view = new Vista();
            Controlador c = new Controlador();
            //INICIALIZA LAS VARIABLES PARA QUE LAS INSTANCIAS FUNCIONES. 
            //ESTAS CREANDO VARIAS INSTANCIAS DE LO MISMO Y POR ESO NO PUEDES HACER 
            //REFERENCIA A ELLO. 

            view.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            c.setView(view);

            //AQUI SETEA LAS INSTANCIAS PARA QUE SOLO EXISTAN UNAS. 
            view.setControlador(c);
            view.setVisible(true);

        }
```

**VISTA**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Vista extends JFrame{
Controlador controlador;

    //ESTOS TE PERMITEN ACCEEDER AL CONTROLADOR QUE SE INICIO EN EL MAIN.
    public Controlador getControlador() {
        return controlador;
    }

    public void setControlador(Controlador controlador) {
       //ESTO ESTA TERRIBLEMENTE MAL. ¿TU CONTROLADOR ES UN KEYLISTENER????
       //DEBES DE CAMBIAR ESTO. NO TIENE NADA QUE VER CON MVC.
        this.addKeyListener(controlador);
        this.controlador = controlador;
    }




public Vista() {
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
    //Esto no funciona asi POR QUE NO TIENES COMO ACCEDER A ESTE CONTROLADOR
    // Y AL QUE ESTA EN EL MAIN. SON DOS OBJETOS DIFERENTES. 
//    this.controlador = new Controlador();
    //ESTO ESCUCHA LAS TECLAS QUE ESTEN EN EL FRAME. 
    this.addKeyListener(controlador);
}
//

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) { // g es un objeto gráfico y contiene los métodos de pintado
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500); // para crear un rectángulo
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    if (controlador.getLetra()!=null) {
    //ESTA ES UNA DE LAS PARTES QUE TE INTERESA. FIJATE COMO ESTOY LLAMANDO
    //A LA INSTANCIA DE controlador y DE AHI AL STRING QUE LUEGO CONVIERTO EN 
    //CHAR. ESTO LO HICE ASI POR COMODIDAD MIA. QUEDATE CON LO QUE TE SIRVA. 
    g.drawChars (controlador.getLetra().toCharArray(), 0, controlador.getLetra().toCharArray().length,10, 60);

    }
 }
}
```

**CONTROLADOR**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Controlador implements KeyListener {

private Vista view;
private Modelo modelo;
String palabraSecreta;
char[] estadoPalabra;
int errores;
private String letra;

    public String getLetra() {
        return letra;
    }

    public void setLetra(String letra) {
        this.letra = letra;
    }



    public Vista getView() {
        return view;
    }

    public void setView(Vista view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public Modelo getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(Modelo modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }




    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        letra = letra + e.getKeyChar();
        view.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

**MODELO**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Modelo {

    static Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    Controlador controlador;

    public Controlador getControlador() {
        return controlador;
    }

    public void setControlador(Controlador controlador) {
        this.controlador = controlador;
    }



    /*** DECLARACIÓN DE VARIABLES ***/

    String[] listaDeportes = {"futbol, baloncesto, balonmano, tenis, ski, padel, ciclismo, natacion, petanca, hipica"};
    int errores;
    char[] estadoPalabra;
    char[] letrasErroneas;
    String palabraSecreta;
    Random numAlea = new Random();
    //ESTA NO SE OCUPA POR QUE SE ACCEDE ATRAVEZ DEL CONTROLADOR. 

//    Vista view;

    /*** CONSTRUCTOR ***/
    //ESTO NO VA A FUNCIONAR ASI. 
//
//    public Modelo(int errores, String palabraSecreta, char[] estadoPalabra) {
//        this.errores = errores;
//        this.palabraSecreta = listaDeportes[(int) (numAlea.nextDouble() * 10)];
//        for (int i = 0; i < palabraSecreta.length(); i++) {
//            this.estadoPalabra[i] = '_';
//        }
//        
//        
//    }

    //AQUI LLAMAMOS A LA FUNCION INICIAR DATO. 
    //COMO NO SE QUE QUIERES HACER AQUI NO LO ARREGLE PERO ASÍ TE VA A 
    //FUNCIONAR MEJOR. SI UTILIZAS EL CONSTRUCTOR TENDRIAS QUE CREAR UNA 
    //CLASE MODELO NUEVA CADA VEZ Y NO QUEREMOS ESO. 
    //TU ARREGLAS ESTA PARTE. 
    public void iniciarDato(int errores, String palabraSecreta, char[] estadoPalabra){
     this.errores = errores;
        this.palabraSecreta = listaDeportes[(int) (numAlea.nextDouble() * 10)];
        for (int i = 0; i < palabraSecreta.length(); i++) {
            this.estadoPalabra[i] = '_';
        }
    }

    public char[] getEstadoPalabra() {
        return estadoPalabra;
    }

    public void verificar(char letra) {

        for (int i = 0; i < palabraSecreta.length(); i++) {
            if (palabraSecreta.toCharArray()[i]==(letra)) {
                estadoPalabra[i] = letra;
            }
            else
                errores++;
        }
    }
}
```

Como dato. Estudia este [link](http://codejavu.blogspot.mx/2013/06/ejemplo-modelo-vista-controlador.html). Lo que estás haciendo no tiene nada que ver con el MVC. Solo estas poniendo sus nombres pero no es así como se lleva a cabo. La manera en que trabajas te va a traer muchos problemas despues. Sería bueno que fueran entrando un poco más en detalle de este u otros modelo que te ayudarán a organizarte mejor.

Cosas que te deben quedar claras:

[POO](http://www.ecodeup.com/4-elementos-claves-para-entender-la-programacion-orientada-objetos-en-java/)
[Que es MVC](https://si.ua.es/es/documentacion/asp-net-mvc-3/1-dia/modelo-vista-controlador-mvc.html)
[Paquetes en java](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paquete_Java)
[Paquetes en netbeans](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrKnfl7mlwM)